# Smartsheet API does not work from command prompt

Tags: python, import, smartsheet-api

I am using the Smartsheet API using python 3.7 anaconda Spyder.
When I run my script from spyder, the script works fine.

When I however use the anaconda prompt, I get a few error messages:
line    8  ,      in       <module>    import smartsheet.
And:
line 31, in  from .smartsheet import Smartsheet, fresh_operation, AbstractUserCalcBackoff  # NOQA,
And:
line 34, in 
from .models import Error, ErrorResult

Does anyone know how to solve these errors?

I already used pip install smartsheet-python-sdk to install it in annaconda.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that Anaconda is not using the same interpreter than Spyder, check this article, https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/integration/python-path/